# cannot execute execl after fork

Tags: c, linux, fork

My goal is to create N process child with one process father.

I am using two files.The first is named forkn.c which contains this code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[] )
{
int status =4;
int i=1;
int wpid;

for (int cpt=0;cpt<atoi(argv[1]);cpt++)
{       
  if (i>0) 
  {
    i=fork();
    if(i>0)
    printf("I create process number %d \n",cpt+1);
  }
}
//The father process created argv [1] son ​​process. This ensures a single father and argv [1] son ​​process

  if(i==0)
  {         
    execl("~/tpBash/tp2/argv[2]","argv[2]",(char*) NULL);
  }

  if (i>0)
  {
    for(int cpt=0;cpt<atoi(argv[1]);cpt++)
    {    
    wait(&status)  ;

    }
    printf("I am the father, I waited all my son processes, I finished \n");

    }

}
```

And there is the code of trait2.c:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
    int status =4;

    printf("I am the child process,my PID is  : %d \n",getpid());
    exit(status);

}
```

After i compile :

```
gcc -std=c99  forkn.c -o forkn
gcc -std=c99 trait2.c -o trait2
```

And then run the executable file :

```
./forkn 3 trait2
```

the first arguments is N (the number of child process to create ) and the second argument is the name of file to execute.
My problem is that the child process does not work.
Any idea please

Comment: Keep in mind that the phrase "son processes" isn't really used. Processes are gender-free as far as I know it, and thus simply called "child processes" when talking about their relation to the parent.

Comment: thanks for the advice.I am not well at english

Comment: Your current code is a fork bomb. You should read more example code that already works and modify it to your needs.

Comment: What is this `"~/tpBash/tp2/argv[2]"` in the statement `execl("~/tpBash/tp2/argv[2]","argv[2]",(char*) NULL);`? As `execl(2)` shows in the manual page, the first argument to `execl(2)` must be the path to the executable you are trying to execute.  And you don't check for `exec(2)` failure (you cannot check for success, but you can for failure).

Comment: @Luis Colorado 
I tried all the possibilties:
         execl("~/tpBash/tp2/argv[2]","argv[2]",(char*) NULL);
         execl("~/tpBash/tp2",argv[2],(char*) NULL);

but it doesn't work !

Comment: @AmirChoubani, is there a subdirectory called `~` in your working directory? (the tilde expansion is a `bash(1)` shell feature, not a kernel feature)  Is there a directory `tpBash` in there?  is there an executable program `tp2` inside?  Do you have execute permission in `~`, in `~/tpBash` and `~/tpBash/tp2` ? And you have to repeat the argument list (including also a second time the program name) for the `execl(2)` call to success.  There's no shell expansion in the string arguments to `execl(2)` so the initial `~` probably is the guilty this time.

Comment: @AmirChoubani, checking for the result of `exec(2)` is not a bad idea.  Just put a `fprintf(stderr, "execl failed: %s (errno = %d)\n", strerror(errno), errno);` after the `execl(2)` call, and include `#include <string.h>` and `#include <errno.h>` at the top of the file.

Answer (score 4):

The problem you are seeing is related to the way you're trying to do string interpolation:

```
execl("~/tpBash/tp2/argv[2]","argv[2]",(char*) NULL);
```

I suggest you try `snprintf`:

```
char buffer[ENOUGH];
snprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, "%s/tpBash/.../...%s", home, argv[2]);
execl(buffer, argv[2]...);
```

Also, the second argument to `execl` should be `argv[2]` and not `"argv[2]"`.

Comment: i =fork();

if(i==1) {//code }

 This prouves that only the parent process will execute the code between brackets

Comment: Also, `execl` is a syscall and doesn't expand `~` to the home directory (that is done by the shell). In other words, `~` must be explicitly interpolated as too: `snprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, "%s/tpBash/.../...%s", getenv("HOME"), argv[2])`

Comment: @user4815162342 Thanks, I somehow missed that there was a `~` there.